# If sale price is equal to zero show only regular product price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I run my woocommerce product updates via xml feed upload. However when a product is not on sale the sale price is set to 0 and some blank.

I want a situation whereby when a product has a sale price of 0 it should only show regular price. I did get it to work with this code

```
add_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'check_sale_price', 40 );
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_sale_price', 40 );
function check_sale_price() {
global $product;
if ( $product->sale_price == '0' ) {
  $price = $product->regular_price;
  $product->sale_price = $price;
  $product->price = $price;
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->get_results( 'UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='.$price.' WHERE meta_key="_sale_price" AND post_id='.$product->id, OBJECT );
  $wpdb->get_results( 'UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='.$price.' WHERE meta_key="_price" AND post_id='.$product->id, OBJECT );
}
}
```

However woocommerce then just displays this below, instead of just regular price.

[image: see what i mean here]

Answer (score 4):

Your code is outdated since Woocommerce 3 and a bit heavy, instead try the following:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'check_sale_price', 1 );
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'check_sale_price', 1 );
function check_sale_price() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->get_sale_price() == '0' ) {
        $product->set_sale_price(''); // Empty sale price
        $product->set_price( $product->get_regular_price() ); // Set regular price back
        $product->save(); // Save and update caches
    }
}

// Change the displayed matching prices (to be sure)
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 10, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    if ( $product->is_on_sale() && $product->get_sale_price() == '0' ) {
        $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ) ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.